# QSqlDatabase: QTDS driver not loaded

Tags: qt, qsqldatabase

I have a program which uses QTDS driver.

in development environment everything workds fine. 
in production i have both the TDS plugin and sybdb available with appropriate rights.

1. -rwxr-xr-x 1 foxprd foxprd    47880 Jan 29 17:33 libqsqltds.so*
2. -rwxr-xr-x 1 foxprd foxprd   472579 Jan 29 17:33 libsybdb.so*

they are both inside a directory which has been added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

and yet i got

```
QSqlDatabase: QTDS driver not loaded
```

**EDIT**
I aslo can tell that:

```
app.libraryPaths()
```

points to a directory in which there is an sqldrivers/ directory containing all the libs
If i rename this direcotry in dev I get the same error, if I put it back it works again.

1. MyappDir/sqldrivers/libqsqltds.so
2. MyappDir/sqldrivers/libsybdb.so
3. MyappDir/sqldrivers/libsybdb.so.5

In dev it works if and only if this directory is here. In Prod it does not work in either case. While “MyappDir/” is always listed in the

```
app.libraryPaths()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self answer:

When a linux app loads it need to be able to access all the libXXX.so it needs. "ld" will look for them in any directory declared in the "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" variable

However Qt seems to load its plugins dynamically from some paths which can be found there:

```
QCoreApplication app(argc,argv);
qDebug() << app.libraryPaths();
```

which printed

("/my/App/Path","/Qt/Dir/Path" )

And from one of this path it should load the plugins. So if in qtDir you have

```
/Qt/Dir/Path/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqltds.so
```

You want to make sure to deploy something like:

```
/my/App/Path/sqldrivers/libqsqltds.so
```

this worked fine because the app path is always in "app.libraryPaths()". However, where things get complicated it that libqsqltds.so requires "libsybdb.so.5" to work properly. Which I knew so there also was a

```
/my/App/Path/sqldrivers/libsybdb.so.5
```

which was wrong because Qt loads dynamically libqsqltds.so but not its dependency, which it seems ld expects to find the usual way ( e.g. in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH )

The fact is that in my dev/integration environments I had libsybdb.so.5 in my path, but not in my production environment.

**So whatever Qt plugins you need make sure to copy the plugin directory ( with only the .so inside ) to your production environment. And Also make sure that performing:**

```
ldd  /my/App/Path/sqldrivers/libsybdb.so.5
```

**will not print any "not found" as these dependency will not appear  with:**

```
ldd  /my/App/Path/myAppBin
```